# Java FX with scenebuilder: Exception running application Start.Main

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I've had this error since I connected the method from the  controller class to the Login.fxml file using scenebuilder. The register button in the login.fxml file is supposed to redirect to the regForm.fxml interface but instead an error occurs.

**The 'Main' class code**

```
package sample;

        import javafx.application.Application;
        import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
        import javafx.scene.Parent;
        import javafx.scene.Scene;
        import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("UGNiP Education portal");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**The 'Controller' class code**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {

    public void regBtnClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Parent regForm = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("regForm.fxml"));
        Scene regScene = new Scene(regForm);

        // To get the stage info
        Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();


        window.setScene(regScene);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

**login page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="294.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="126.0" text="UGNiP Login Page">
         <font>
            <Font size="43.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="66.0" layoutY="78.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="44.0" text="I.D: ">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField layoutX="126.0" layoutY="74.0" promptText="123456789" />
      <Label layoutX="309.0" layoutY="78.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Password:">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <PasswordField layoutX="401.0" layoutY="74.0" promptText="******" />
      <Button layoutX="253.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Login" />
      <Button layoutX="344.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#regBtnClicked" text="Register" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Registration form XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <TextField layoutX="130.0" layoutY="119.0" promptText="John" />
        <TextField layoutX="408.0" layoutY="119.0" promptText="Doe" />
        <TextField layoutX="130.0" layoutY="175.0" promptText="123456789" />
        <PasswordField layoutX="408.0" layoutY="175.0" promptText="********" />
        <TextField layoutX="130.0" layoutY="224.0" promptText="example@example.com" />
        <TextField layoutX="408.0" layoutY="224.0" promptText="0771234567" />
        <Label layoutX="36.0" layoutY="123.0" text="First Name: " />
        <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="179.0" text="Identification code: " />
        <Label layoutX="52.0" layoutY="228.0" text="Email:" />
        <Label layoutX="322.0" layoutY="123.0" text="Last Name: " />
        <Label layoutX="325.0" layoutY="179.0" text="Password: " />
        <Label layoutX="299.0" layoutY="228.0" text="Telephone Number: " />
        <Button layoutX="244.0" layoutY="298.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Confirm Registration " />
        <Button layoutX="32.0" layoutY="354.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Back" />
        <Label layoutX="225.0" layoutY="42.0" text="Registration ">
            <font>
                <Font size="30.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Button layoutX="248.0" layoutY="354.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancel Registration " />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Error message in console**

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#regBtnClicked', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/C:/Users/muizu/Documents/codes/cwk3/out/production/cwk3/sample/Login.fxml:31

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: `Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#regBtnClicked', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.`

Comment: Not the cause of the exception, but you should not use the same controller class for two different FXML files.

Comment: I'm not using the same controller for the other fxml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller for the `login.fxml` should have a method named `regBtnClicked` in it.

```
@FXML private void regBtnClicked(ActionEvent event)
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Your code seems to be missing the '@FXML' part. Also, change `import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;` to a `JavaFX` import.

Comment: @Sedrick The OP's controller already has this method. `@FXML` is not needed if the method is `public` (which it is in that version). This does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was not needed if the method is public. So it basically boils down to the duplicate question.